# Performance limitations of web vs desktop applications?

Tags: java, reactjs, web-applications

The project we are working on is a data-intensive real-time application. We are trying to decide whether to make the front-end a desktop (in Java with JavaFX) or web app (in ReactJS). Making it a web app would have many advantages. But we are concerned about performance. We cannot afford to write it as a web app only to discover that it becomes slow or lags under heavy load afterwards. The front-end will have to handle a complex UI and large datasets (potentially with millions of entries).

One thing that particularly concerns us that we could not find any examples of large scale real-time web apps handling the amount of data ours will have to handle. That makes us wonder if it is possible at all.

My research suggests that desktop apps have access to more resources than web apps running in a browser and therefore are able to outperform them.

Comment: I'm working on migrating a desktop application to ReactJS for a real-time pricing application. I would say that the browser is not as performant when it comes to rendering the UI, especially if it includes intensive UI rendering. UI rendering is single-threaded in the browser but not for desktop application frameworks

Comment: @codemax Actually both Swing and JavaFX are single threaded.  But they’re still likely to be better performers than a browser based UI.

Comment: @VGR Yes probably more performant. Also we have no control over the browser engine. There are so many possibilities with custom `JVMs`. Also AFAIK, `.NET` supports multi-threading for UI, so that definitely makes it faster than browser UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user interface should only handle as much data as the user can handle. Can your users read a million data records per second? Probably not. So design the interaction between the user interface and the backend so that the UI only has to process the data the user can consume. You would apply techniques like lazy-loading and paging.

Browser based applications might still not be as fast as native applications, but for most purposes they are "fast enough." But you're not even comparing native to browser, you're comparing *Java Swing* to browser. In some benchmarks, the Chrome "V8" JavaScript execution engine beats Java. It's not at all clear if a Java Swing UI would be faster or slower than a ReactJS UI.

It is certainly not ideal to commit to a technology and discover months later that it's not going to work out. I would recommend you develop a quick **throw-away prototype** to get an idea of where the pain points may lie.

Comment: The Java Client would be using JavaFX not Swing. I will edit my question to clarify.

Comment: The throw-away prototype is a good recommendation. I will do that.

Comment: I doubt swing vs javafx matters much here, swing has a lot of history behind it and they've worked out most of the problems by now, on the other hand javafx is newer and lighter weight and doesn't have the baggage swing does...

Comment: I would have assumed that JavaFX would outperform ReactJS just because it has access to more resources. You don't think so?

Comment: No. The resources are the same. If anything ReactJS running in a web browser has access to more efficient resources: hardware accelerated image codecs, animation, etc

Comment: @2um9YJ6haZ7wKP4m Hey were you able to create this app with ReactJS?, my team is having the same issue with this

Comment: @Ángel Yes, we were/still are. We are now using [Reason](https://reasonml.github.io/) and [ReasonReact](https://reasonml.github.io/reason-react/). Reason compiles to JavaScript. It performs well and Joni was right that we could significantly reduce the amount of data the frontend needed to handle by redesigning.